# How to create a function to search and create a json list

Tags: javascript, json, function

I tried to create a function and pass the parameter that is for him to search and return the list, however, he looks for "parameter" instead of "cardapio"

function I want to call:

```
gerenateList(cardapio);
gerenateList(payments);
```

function that I created

```
export function generateList(parameter){
    let menu = dataJson.parameter.map((i) => {
        return `*${i.id}* - ${i.name}\n`;
        
    });
return menu;
```

dataJson.json

```
{
 "cardapio":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"X-Burguer",
            "type":"Burguer",
            "price":"9.99"
        }, {
            "id":2,
            "name":"X-Salada",
            "type":"Burguer",
            "price":"9.99"
        }, {
            "id":3,
            "name":"X-Tudo",
            "type":"Burguer",
            "price":"9.99"
        }],
"payments":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Dinheiro",
            "type":"Money"
        }, {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Cartão de débito",
            "type":"Debit"
        }, {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Cartão de crédito - Visa",
            "type":"Visa"
        }]
}
```

desired exit result

```
//cardapio
*1* - X-Burguer
*2* - X-Salada
*3* - X-Tudo

//payments
*1* - Dinheiro
*2* - Cartão de débito
*3* - Cartão de crédito - Visa
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is in this line:

```
dataJson.parameter
```

Change it with:

```
dataJson[parameter]
```

```js
var dataJson = {
    "cardapio": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "X-Burguer",
            "type": "Burguer",
            "price": "9.99"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "X-Salada",
            "type": "Burguer",
            "price": "9.99"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "X-Tudo",
            "type": "Burguer",
            "price": "9.99"
        }],
    "payments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Dinheiro",
            "type": "Money"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Cartão de débito",
            "type": "Debit"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Cartão de crédito - Visa",
            "type": "Visa"
        }]
};

function gerenateList(parameter) {
    let menu = dataJson[parameter].map(function (i) {
        return `*${i.id}* - ${i.name}\n`;
    });
    return menu;
}

var result = gerenateList('cardapio');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you could also add some validation in case the Object does not have the given key `Object.keys(dataJson).map(key => { if(key == parameter) {...}})` or `if(Object.keys(dataJson).find(key => key == parameter) !== undefined)`

Comment: it worked well man, thank you very much